# converting obj c to swift HBVLinkedTextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I wanted to find which text users tap and i think HBVLinkedTextView looks good to find, so i want to convert https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView/blob/master/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/ViewController.m 
it to swift , 
I'm new to swift and never really tried objective-C , and this is what i did so far (Right now im just testing this with Hashtags #)

```
func thedemo() {

        var textstr:NSString = "is @detected in a specified substring of the textview's text. You can set attributes and tap handling #blocks for #linked strings individually, by @passing in an array of strings, or with a @regular #expression."

        self.linkedText.text = textstr

        var error:NSError?
        var regex:NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#(\\w+)", options: nil, error: nil)!
        var atr : NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
        var defaultAttributes : NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()]


        self.linkedText.linkStringsWithRegEx(regex, defaultAttributes: defaultAttributes, highlightedAttributes: atr, tapHandler: self.exampleHandlerWithTitle("tag found"))

    }
```

I'm currently stuck on

```
- (LinkedStringTapHandler)exampleHandlerWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    LinkedStringTapHandler exampleHandler = ^(NSString *linkedString) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title
                                                       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handle tap in linked string '%@'",linkedString]
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    };

    return exampleHandler;
}
```

How do i convert this func to swift?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is your problem exactly?
What didn't works?

Comment: I want to convert this func to swift **- (LinkedStringTapHandler)exampleHandlerWithTitle:(NSString *)title**

Comment: @LastMove **LinkedStringTapHandler exampleHandler = ^(NSString *linkedString)** this line has block, not sure how to convert it to swift